# Example of a Riemann integrable function, which is not bounded?

Tags: integration, analysis, riemann-integration

I have to give an example of a function which is Riemann integrable on [0,+∞) but its not bounded. I know about the connection of Riemann Integrability and bounded functions, but this is my assignment and I think there is an intention behind it.

I thought about 1/x. We have done the integral of 1/x and the result is +∞. Would that work?

Edit: I understood that the function 1/x would not work. Would maybe the function f(x)=x work?

Comment: Something got distorted in this question. As the answer of @Botond shows, the very definition of Riemann integrability requires, as a precondition, a bounded function on a closed interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac 1 {\sqrt x}$ has finite improper Riemann integral on $[0,1]$.

Comment: I am sorry but I am still unclear...

Comment: If the function is not bounded, we speak about umproper integral.

Comment: $\int_r^{1}\frac 1 {\sqrt x} dx=2 (\sqrt x |_r^{1})=2(1-\sqrt r) \to 2$ as $ r \to 0$.

Comment: But 1/x would also work,right?

Comment: No, it doesn't because $\int_0^{1} \frac 1 x dx=\infty$.

Comment: so that´s not improper?

Comment: $\frac  1 x$ is not Riemann integrable and it does not even have a finite improper  Riemann integral so it is not a valid example.

Comment: thanks very much

Comment: would also the identity function f(x)=x work?

Comment: @mate98 The identity function is bounded on a finite interval. On an infinite interval it is not Riemann integrable. Hence it does not serve as  a counter-example.

Answer (score 2):

Riemann integral is defined for bounded functions on a finite interval, so neither unbounded functions nor functions on an infinite interval can be Riemann integrated.

On the other hand, you can have an unbounded, improper Riemann integrable function on $[0, +\infty)$, simply by extending Kavi's example from $[0,1]$ to $[0, +\infty)$. For example
$$f(x)= \begin{cases} 
      0 & x= 0 \\
      \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} & 0< x\leqslant1 \\
      \frac{1}{x^2} & x > 1 
   \end{cases}
$$
will do the job.

Comment: may i ask if this function would also be continuous?

Comment: It would also be very helpful for me to know why Kavi's example works only on [0,1] and not in [0,infinity].

Comment: @mate98 the problem with Kavi's function is that the integral diverges at infinity.

Comment: @mate98 My example is continuous on $(0,+\infty)$

Answer (score 0):

$x \mapsto 1/x$ does not work as the integral

$$\int_0^\infty 1/x dx = +\infty$$

is not finite.